# How to create a dummy variable that takes the value 1 if all values of a variable within a group exceed a certain value

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dummy-variable

I have a data set like the one below:

```
dat <- data.frame (id  = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                   year = c(2015, 2016, 2017,2018, 2019, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019),
                   ratio=c(0.6,0.6,0.65,0.7,0.8,0.4,1,0.5,0.3,0.7))

dat
   id year ratio
1   1 2015  0.60
2   1 2016  0.60
3   1 2017  0.65
4   1 2018  0.70
5   1 2019  0.80
6   2 2015  0.40
7   2 2016  1.00
8   2 2017  0.50
9   2 2018  0.30
10  2 2019  0.70
```

I'd like to create a dummy variable that takes the value of 1 if all the values of the ratio variable within each id exceed 0.5. The resulting data set should be as follows:

```
dat
   id year ratio dummy
1   1 2015  0.60     1
2   1 2016  0.60     1
3   1 2017  0.65     1
4   1 2018  0.70     1
5   1 2019  0.80     1
6   2 2015  0.40     0
7   2 2016  1.00     0
8   2 2017  0.50     0
9   2 2018  0.30     0
10  2 2019  0.70     0
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `transform(dat, dummy = ave(ratio, id, FUN = \(x) all(x > .5)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a base R answer in comments. Here is a `dplyr` and `data.table` version -

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(dummy = as.integer(all(ratio > 0.5))) %>%
  ungroup

#      id  year ratio dummy
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1  2015  0.6      1
# 2     1  2016  0.6      1
# 3     1  2017  0.65     1
# 4     1  2018  0.7      1
# 5     1  2019  0.8      1
# 6     2  2015  0.4      0
# 7     2  2016  1        0
# 8     2  2017  0.5      0
# 9     2  2018  0.3      0
#10     2  2019  0.7      0
```

`data.table` -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)[, dummy := as.integer(all(ratio > 0.5)), id]
dat
```